# How to extract an ID from a request's subsample or body in Jmeter & save it in CSV

Tags: regex, csv, response, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am a beginner in `Jmeter` & trying to save an ID `(like ID=1234567)` in a HTTP request's response data using `regex` extractor & a 3rd party plugin called Dummy sampler with `Filewriter` but I am failing every time. Here is what it looks like:

```
/Registration/PaymentInformation?accountRegistrationId=372036
```

My objective is to save these `accountRegistrationId` in a CSV file & then use them in the following request as a parameter. The only part where I am stuck is capturing them & saving a file. After that I can manage. I have googled everywhere but cant find a solution. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Following regex should work - `(.*accountRegistrationId=)([0-9]+)(.*)`
Use `$2$` to retrieve the id.

[JMeter regex reference](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)